# sftp from Java give "connection closed" after many files have been transferred ok

Tags: sftp, jsch

Java program copying a lot of files from a Raspberry PI to a Mac. Using jsch-0.1.55.jar
Using:

```
secureFtp s = new secureFtp();

do for 1000 files 
s.sftpPut(host, user, pwd, sFile, destFullpath, iLastMod);
end
```

Sends 50 or 100 files ok, then error "com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: connection is closed by foreign host"
Network should be stable. But looks like the sftp server at receiver is a bit stressed.
Should have a "sleep" between each put, perhaps..
Or any other hints?

Comment: There's no `secureFtp` class in JSch. We need [mcve]. + Evidence (like a log file) that a successful transfer of all your files using any commandline/GUI SFTP client (or any other SFTP library) is possible on the same machine that runs your Java JSch code.

Comment: Some servers will throttle connections and only allow N transfers or N gigabytes or whatever per some unit time. The joyous part is that often those running the server won't tell you what the limits are (I have to deal with this at work, where we have to deal with vendors who throttle their SFTP servers but won't tell us, their client, what the limits are). The "solution" is to add a sleep after every few files. You know you've got it right if you don't get summarily disconnected.